# How Do You Add A Replay Button To A Game?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Im trying to make a replay button for my game where when you die the game pauses until you press the space bar which resets the game so you can play again. I'm using python with pygame. If you can fix this, please do! It would make my day. If possible, please include the code for the fix and where to put it because I am new to python. The source code below is the game I'm working on.

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
import time

pygame.init()

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

TRASH = (110, 110, 110)
RED = (135, 56, 47)
player_pos = [400, 475]
player_size = 50
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

enemy_size = 50

SPEED = 11

FPS = 120

enemy_pos = [random.randint(0, WIDTH - enemy_size), 0]
enemy_list = [enemy_pos]

game_over = False

score = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 35)

pygame.display.set_caption('Crab Dodge,  By: ChanceMeteor515')

pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)


def drop_enemies(enemy_list):
    if len(enemy_list) < 9:
        x_pos = random.randint(0, WIDTH - enemy_size)
        y_pos = 10
        enemy_list.append([x_pos, y_pos])


def draw_enemies(enemy_list):
    for enemy_pos in enemy_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, TRASH, (enemy_pos[0], enemy_pos[1], enemy_size, enemy_size))


def update_enemies_pos(enemy_list, score):
    for idx, enemy_pos in enumerate(enemy_list):
        if enemy_pos[1] >= 0 and enemy_pos[1] < HEIGHT:
            enemy_pos[1] += SPEED
        else:
            enemy_list.pop(idx)
            score += 1
        return score


def collision_check(enemy_list, player_pos):
    for enemy_pos in enemy_list:
        if detect_collision(enemy_pos, player_pos):
            return True
        return False


def edge_detection1(player_pos):
    if player_pos[0] > 750:
        return True
    return False


def edge_detection2(player_pos):
    if player_pos[0] < 0:
        return True
    return False


def detect_collision(player_pos, enemy_pos):
    p_x = player_pos[0]
    p_y = player_pos[1]

    e_x = enemy_pos[0]
    e_y = enemy_pos[1]

    if (e_x >= p_x and e_x < (p_x + player_size)) or (p_x >= e_x and p_x < (e_x + enemy_size)):
        if (e_y >= p_y and e_y < (p_y + player_size)) or (p_y >= e_y and p_y < (e_y + enemy_size)):
            return True
        return False

while not game_over:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            x = player_pos[0]
            y = player_pos[1]
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x -= player_size
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x += player_size
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x -= player_size
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x += player_size
            elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                x -= player_size
            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()

            player_pos = [x, y]
    screen.fill((194, 178, 128))

    drop_enemies(enemy_list)
    score = update_enemies_pos(enemy_list, score)

    text = "Score:" + str(score)
    label = myFont.render(text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(label, (WIDTH - 200, HEIGHT - 40))

    if edge_detection1(player_pos):
       player_pos[0] = 0

    if edge_detection2(player_pos):
        player_pos[0] = 750

    if collision_check(enemy_list, player_pos):
        time.sleep(1.4)
        game_over = True
    draw_enemies(enemy_list)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (player_pos[0], player_pos[1], player_size, player_size))
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've done what you've wanted but it requires Tkinter cause I was a bit lazy.

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
import time
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
print(os.getcwd())

pygame.init()


def game():
  WIDTH = 800
  HEIGHT = 600

  TRASH = (110, 110, 110)
  RED = (135, 56, 47)
  player_pos = [400, 475]
  player_size = 50
  game_over = False
  screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

  enemy_size = 50

  SPEED = 11

  FPS = 120

  enemy_pos = [random.randint(0, WIDTH - enemy_size), 0]
  enemy_list = [enemy_pos]


  score = 0

  clock = pygame.time.Clock()

  myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 35)

  pygame.display.set_caption('Crab Dodge,  By: ChanceMeteor515')

  pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)


  def drop_enemies(enemy_list):
      if len(enemy_list) < 9:
          x_pos = random.randint(0, WIDTH - enemy_size)
          y_pos = 10
          enemy_list.append([x_pos, y_pos])


  def draw_enemies(enemy_list):
      for enemy_pos in enemy_list:
          pygame.draw.rect(screen, TRASH, (enemy_pos[0], enemy_pos[1], enemy_size, enemy_size))


  def update_enemies_pos(enemy_list, score):
      for idx, enemy_pos in enumerate(enemy_list):
          if enemy_pos[1] >= 0 and enemy_pos[1] < HEIGHT:
              enemy_pos[1] += SPEED
          else:
              enemy_list.pop(idx)
              score += 1
          return score


  def collision_check(enemy_list, player_pos):
      for enemy_pos in enemy_list:
          if detect_collision(enemy_pos, player_pos):
              return True
          return False


  def edge_detection1(player_pos):
      if player_pos[0] > 750:
          return True
      return False
  
  
  def edge_detection2(player_pos):
      if player_pos[0] < 0:
          return True
      return False


  def detect_collision(player_pos, enemy_pos):
      p_x = player_pos[0]
      p_y = player_pos[1]
  
      e_x = enemy_pos[0]
      e_y = enemy_pos[1]
  
      if (e_x >= p_x and e_x < (p_x + player_size)) or (p_x >= e_x and p_x < (e_x + enemy_size)):
          if (e_y >= p_y and e_y < (p_y + player_size)) or (p_y >= e_y and p_y < (e_y + enemy_size)):
              return True
          return False
  
  while not game_over:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              sys.exit()
          if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
              x = player_pos[0]
              y = player_pos[1]
              if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                  x -= player_size
              elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                  x += player_size
              elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                  x -= player_size
              elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                  x += player_size
              elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                  x -= player_size
              elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                  sys.exit()

              player_pos = [x, y]
      screen.fill((194, 178, 128))

      drop_enemies(enemy_list)
      score = update_enemies_pos(enemy_list, score)

      text = "Score:" + str(score)
      label = myFont.render(text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
      screen.blit(label, (WIDTH - 200, HEIGHT - 40))
  
      if edge_detection1(player_pos):
         player_pos[0] = 0
  
      if edge_detection2(player_pos):
          player_pos[0] = 750

      if collision_check(enemy_list, player_pos):
          time.sleep(1.4)
          Tk().wm_withdraw() #to hide the main window
          game_over = True
      draw_enemies(enemy_list)
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (player_pos[0], player_pos[1], player_size, player_size))
      clock.tick(FPS)
      pygame.display.update()
  ans = messagebox.askretrycancel("askretrycancel", "Try again?")
  root=Tk()
  root.destroy()
  return ans
while True:
  if game() == True:
    pass
  else:
    break
```

Comment: Does it work? Pls let me know

Comment: Accept the answer if it does

Comment: Ummm, it started working and then it just froze. Thanks for answering tho

Comment: Nvm I changed just a little bit and it worked.

Comment: btw Tk().wm_withdraw() did not hide the main window is I just deleted it/

Comment: ok thanks for letting me know